# Use class from another OSGi bundle

Tags: java, export, osgi, bundle

I'm running in a strange issue with OSGi bundle.

I've got two bundle, let's say `B1` and `B2`.
`B1` export the package `a.b.c` which contain a class name `Foo` with a method:

```
public JsonNode helloWorld() {
    System.out.println("Hello World!");
    return null;
}
```

Then `B2` import `B1` package and try to use the class `Foo` from `B1`. I have no problem at compilation, neither when starting the bundle in Felix, everything seem to work fine.

BUT when `B2` is call to use the `helloWorld` method, `B2` stop working and do not throw any error !
After some debug I figure the return type of the method `helloWorld` is the cause, if I change `JsonNode` to `String` everything work as expected.

Why I haven't error in my felix console ? Why I can't call the `helloWorld` method when the return type is JsonNode ?

Thanks for help !

Edit1: More information, the following method does the exact same bug:

```
 public String helloWorld() {
     System.out.println("Hello World!");
     JsonNode test =  JsonNodeFactory.instance.objectNode();
     return test.asText();
 }
```

I see in the console the Hello World! Then nothing, no error, no trace, just like if the program choose to stop here and wait !

Edit2: 
<strike>I have this warning when building, I don't know if it's important:</strike>

```
[WARNING] Bundle fr.aaa.ccc.bbbb:1.0.0 : Export javax.json,  has 1,  private references [javax.json.stream],
```

Warning remove, still got the same comportement.

Edit3:
I manage to get an error in my console and I think i'm closed to find out what's the problem !!!

```
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: 
loader constraint violation: 
when resolving interface method "a.b.c.FooInterface.welcome(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/codehaus/jackson/JsonNode;"
the class loader (instance of org/apache/felix/framework/BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoaderJava5) 
of the current class, d/e/f/lasthope/Activator, 
and the class loader (instance of org/apache/felix/framework/BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoaderJava5) for the method's defining class, a/b/c/aa/bb/FooInterface,
have different Class objects for the type org/codehaus/jackson/JsonNode used in the signature
    at d.e.f.Activator.start(Activator.java:37)
```

Comment: Please post the StackTrace.

Comment: As as say, there's no stacktrace at all. I have put a log message just before and just after the call of helloWorld method. The first log message appear in console but the second never show up. No error, no stacktrace, nothing ><

Answer (score 0):

I guess you call the method in a BundleActivator. A common problem there is that exceptions in e.g. the start method are not logged. So try to use try catch around the call to helloworld and print or log the exception.

I think the problem with JsonNode is that bundle B2 does not see the class or B1 sees a different class. Make sure that both bundles import the package JsonNode is in.

Comment: I have already a try catch block surrounding the helloWorld call with System.out, printStackTrace and log in the catch block to be sure I'll know if I get there.
My two bundle have as dependency javax.json and I verify, the two got the same exact library name and version in "Maven Dependencies".

Comment: Does you Manifest have an Import-Package for the package of JsonNode? Make sure you do not embed the Json classes. It would help a lot if you cold provide the code for your bundles somewhere.